# Display a value of a button on a JSP Page in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a JSP page with multiple products. Each product has a button which calls a model that is included in the page with JSP:INCLUDE.
We put the modal code into a separate JSP to organize it better.

We want to use this modal and display the text based on a value that we pass from the button that has been clicked to the modal. Its like Button for "product one" will display the text in the modal "Product one" and maybe some other text.

I searched on stackoverflow and on google but i couldnt find some hints to archive this. I tried with JSP:PARAM and JSP INCLUDE but this is on a page level. I need it for every button a user clicks a different text on the header for example.

....
Button to book the tour.

```
<button data-aos="fade-up-right" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-offset="100" class="gold-btn call-us" onClick="document.getElementId('action').value=this.value;return true;">Book Tour</button>
```

It calls a modal called "call-us"

Code of "call-us" modal:

```
<div class="callback">
    <div class="callus--modal">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">  
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-right">   
                    <div class="callus-close">X</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">  
                    <img src="http://www.roma-vaticano.com/assets/images/common/divider.png">
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">  
                    <h2>${param.booking_title}</h2>
                    <h3>We will call you back</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form id="callback-form">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="callback_name" value="" placeholder="First and Last Name *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-4 medium-4 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="prefix" id="callback_prefix" maxlength="3" value="" placeholder="prefix *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="cell large-8 medium-8 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="callback_phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="callback_email" value="" placeholder="email address *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <div class="autorizzazione" style="text-align: left;">
                        <div class="check_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="si" id="callback_auth" name="privacy" required>
                            <label for="e_auth"></label>
                        </div> 
                        <p>I confirm that i have read the privacy policy. *</p>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="autorizzazione" style="text-align: left;">
                        <div class="check_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="si" id="callback_newsletter" name="newsletter">
                            <label for="e_auth"></label>
                        </div> 
                        <p>I want to recieve special offers about Rome and the Vatican</p>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                        <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                            <input class="gold-btn" id="callback_submit" type="submit" value="CALL ME BACK" style="border: none !important; position: relative; float: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>


$("#callback-form").validate({
   errorClass: "contact-error",
   validClass: "contact-valid",
   rules: {
    name: "required",
    prefix: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 3
    },
    phone: "required",
    email: "required",
    privacy: "required"
  },
  messages: {},
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    sendCallbackEmail();
  }
});

function sendCallbackEmail() {
    var name = $('#callback_name').val();
    var prefix = $('#callback_prefix').val();
    var phone = $('#callback_phone').val();
        var email = $('#callback_email').val();

    var params = {};
    params.name = name;
    params.prefix = prefix;
    params.phone = phone;
        params.email = email;
    $.get( "/contacts/callback", params ).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('#callback_submit').val("SENT");
            $("#callback_submit").prop("disabled",true);
        } else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

As you can see we tried it with JSP:PARAM and this works. But not on a button level it displays the same value for every button which is normal. The place where `${param.booking_title}` is located in the modal there should be the text of the value that will be passed from the button to the modal displayed.
We want to add different text on every button of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsp:param` works for value set in backend (server).

But if you want to `modify DOM element without sending requests` (like `h:button, h:link`), you need to call js function and modify it.

Set `id` for you h2 element and call `showDlg` function

```js
function showDlg(text){
    
    $("#booking-title").text(text);
    $(".callback").show();
    document.getElementById('action').value=this.value;
    return true;
}

$("#callback-form").validate({
   errorClass: "contact-error",
   validClass: "contact-valid",
   rules: {
    name: "required",
    prefix: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 3
    },
    phone: "required",
    email: "required",
    privacy: "required"
  },
  messages: {},
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    sendCallbackEmail();
  }
});

function sendCallbackEmail() {
    var name = $('#callback_name').val();
    var prefix = $('#callback_prefix').val();
    var phone = $('#callback_phone').val();
        var email = $('#callback_email').val();

    var params = {};
    params.name = name;
    params.prefix = prefix;
    params.phone = phone;
        params.email = email;
    $.get( "/contacts/callback", params ).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('#callback_submit').val("SENT");
            $("#callback_submit").prop("disabled",true);
        } else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<button data-aos="fade-up-right" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-offset="100" class="gold-btn call-us" onClick="showDlg('Book Tour')">Book Tour</button>
<input type="hidden" id="action" />

<hr/>

<div class="callback" style="display:none">
    <div class="callus--modal">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">  
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-right">   
                    <div class="callus-close">X</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">  
                    <img src="http://www.roma-vaticano.com/assets/images/common/divider.png">
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">  
                    <h2 id="booking-title">${param.booking_title}</h2>
                    <h3>We will call you back</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form id="callback-form">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="callback_name" value="" placeholder="First and Last Name *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-4 medium-4 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="prefix" id="callback_prefix" maxlength="3" value="" placeholder="prefix *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="cell large-8 medium-8 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="callback_phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number *" required>
                </div>
                                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="callback_email" value="" placeholder="email address *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                    <div class="autorizzazione" style="text-align: left;">
                        <div class="check_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="si" id="callback_auth" name="privacy" required>
                            <label for="e_auth"></label>
                        </div> 
                        <p>I confirm that i have read the privacy policy. *</p>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="autorizzazione" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <div class="check_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="si" id="callback_newsletter" name="newsletter">
                            <label for="e_auth"></label>
                        </div> 
                        <p>I want to recieve special offers about Rome and the Vatican</p>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                        <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 text-center">
                            <input class="gold-btn" id="callback_submit" type="submit" value="CALL ME BACK" style="border: none !important; position: relative; float: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Valijon, thanks for the solution. I tested it and it worked. But i noticed that if i include the code of the callback modal with the javascript with <jsp:include> into the page the text will not be displayed. It has to be in the same JSP File as the HTML where the button code is. I am wondering why JSP:Include doesnt work here. The reason for the include is that we can make the code for the callback form and reuse it on multiple pages. If a JSP native solution what also work i am interested to know.

Comment: The solutions works now. I think i forgot some code in the file that is included with js:include. If i want to add more values to the button like "booking-title2" and display it somewhere else in the modal too would that also be possible or are we only able with the button to use one value we can pass to the modal? I also checkde the h:button solution to use the server side but this seems to work only with JSF but we are using JSP. If we could use server side with multiple values that would be nice too. Thanks a lot.